# Android 2.3 API is not available as a target option for AVD

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am new to android development, and I am trying to create an AVD for testing an app before pushing it to my phone (htc desire running android 2.3.5).

I am using the ADT bundle, and with SDK manager I have downloaded these:

1. 4.2.2 (API 17)
2. 4.1.2 (API 16)
3. 2.3.3 (API 10)
4. 2.2 (API 8)

But when trying to select target of the AVD, the only available options are API 17,16 and 8.

What is wrong?

**Update:**
I've already tried deleting and redownloading the API and it shows up in the android-sdk/platforms dir.

Comment: try dowmloading or updating the api again from sdk manager...

Comment: you can select the particular api from sdk manager and update it...

Comment: @KaranMer: I've already did that :/ (I've also updated my question with this)

Comment: if your friends have the desired api with them...simply try copying the folder from platforms and paste them in your platforms folder...

Comment: give it a try... i guess it works

Answer (score 9):

Restart eclipse after install packages i also have same problem and after restart eclipse i got all api levels in drop down list

Comment: Thanks man, I had the same problem and implemented your suggestion & voila! It worked!

Comment: Same here, also with 2.3.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem because I had downloaded the sdk twice and my SDK manager kept updating first SDK while my IDE was working with the other one. SO check the preferences of your IDE and see if it points to the correct one. (in Eclipse go to windows>  preferences> SDK location)

Answer (score 2):

For Android 2.3.3, there will be three entries of relevance in the SDK Manager:

- "SDK Platform", which for older API levels like 10 will contain the ARM emulator image
- "Google APIs", which will contain an emulator image that has Google Maps in it
- "Intel Atom x86 System Image", which will contain an emulator image that runs x86 opcodes instead of ARM opcodes (and, with the proper setup of your development machine, can run the emulator much faster)

If you install one or more of these, you should get API Level 10 appearing an an option for setting up an AVD.

If that does not work, you might consider editing your question and posting screenshots of your SDK Manager (specifically the 2.3.3 portion) and the AVD Manager (specifically your drop-down of available API levels).

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the 2.3.3 API.
And you can also try to use BlueStacks if you wish to first test your app before trying it on your device.

Answer (score 0):

Delete that api from SDK Manager and download it again.